# One query on multiple collections with MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose

I have multiple collections in mongoDB which are totally independent (no embedded / reference / id fields...). You can imagine cars, houses and boats for example.

After a search result from elasticsearch on multiple collections, I would like to hydrate the returned documents based on their `_id` by requesting mongoDB. I am already making one request by collection and it works fine, but I would like to know if it is possible to do it in one request for all collections.

(I don't think aggregation or mapreduce could be a solution here as collections are uncorrelated and I don't want "merge" collection documents together)

**Questions**

Is it possible with mongodb or mongoose to make one query to get documents from all my collections at once ? Should I make one request by collection as I am already doing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not possible at the moment. Please keep an eye on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23201 when it is implemented.

Comment: Thank you, it was the answer I was looking for :)